# "A sharing violation occurred" - caused by not-closed stream?

Tags: java, windows, file, inputstream

I'm developing a tool for Minecraft resource packs, basically it shows tree structure, previews of images and lets you edit some things.

It works great on Linux, but Windows users keep reporting bugs like this:

> I'm having an error that won't let me save my new textures after
>   editing them with paint:
>
> **A sharing violation occurred while accessing** 
>   C:\Users\Me\Appdata\Roaming.mcRPW\tmp\workdir\project_files\assets\minecraft\textures\blocks\repeater_off.png

I use `InputStream` for reading the previews, and as it turns out, the method doesn't close it after it's done with it. I assumed garbage collector would take care of that, but maybe I was wrong. Anyway I have no idea what's going on, I can edit the images just fine on Linux.

This reading is about the only way my Java application interacts with the file.

Is my suspicion correct? If no, how to fix it?

Comment: It would help if you posted the code. You must call _close()_ on any stream you open either explicitly in a _finally_ block or preferably using [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @McDowell the code wouldn't show anything more than what I described. I'm not closing the stream. Now I made a patch release which uses finally and closes it, but I want to know if this is really the cause for all the problems or not.

Comment: Yes, that's the cause of the problem.  (How do you expect `InputStream` to know that you're done with the file if you don't close it?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I figured it'd close itself when GC calls `finalize()` on it. Apparently that's not the case.

Comment: @MightyPork: yes, it will close when it is finalized.  But that doesn't happen deterministically - and won't happen at all if the `InputStream` object is still in scope.  (I don't know whether that's the case or not, since you've refused to post your code.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston It's a method which opens stream, loads image and returns the image, so I don't think it's in scope. Anyway I'll start closing the stream now and hope it'll fix the problems.